# BUG! Custom font does not always work in IE10 and 11

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer, font-face

I did not test fully, but I'm confident every browser handles this correctly except IE10+. Surprisingly, IE9 did work correctly.

**Code to reproduce bug**

This is the minimal code required to reproduce this bug.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            @font-face {
                font-family: 'SassoonInfant';
                src: url('../fonts/SassoonInfant.eot');
                src: url('../fonts/SassoonInfant.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
                     url('../fonts/SassoonInfant.woff') format('woff'),
                     url('../fonts/SassoonInfant.ttf') format('truetype'),
                     url('../fonts/SassoonInfant.svg') format('svg');
                font-weight: normal;
                font-style: normal;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div style="font-family: arial;">
            <div style="font-family: SassoonInfant;">
                I'm already here in the SassoonInfant font, this makes no difference, unless the parent of this div is also SassoonInfant!
            </div>
        </div>
        <div style="font-family: arial;">
            <div style="font-family: aoeuaoeu;"><!--any invalid font-family-->
                This text will be Times New Roman (the default), in any case. Thus it is similar to what happens to the dynamically added element.
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="container" style="font-family: SassoonInfant;"></div>
        <script>
            (function() //-> window.onload does not make a difference
            {
                var txt = document.createElement('div');
                setTimeout(function(){
                    // the following three statements have to be in this exact order (and at least these three within the timeout):
                    txt.style.fontFamily = 'SassoonInfant, verdana';
                    txt.innerHTML = 'This text is <b>not</b> SassoonInfant when you define a font-family for it in any element if any parent also has this custom font as font-family. IE sucks!';
                    document.getElementById('container').appendChild(txt);
                }, 400);
            })();
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Bug result in IE11**

The result of this bug is that a dynamically added child with the same `font-family` custom-font as one of its parents, will make the font in that child fallback to the default (this can also be 'verdana', as in: `font-family: SassoonInfant, verdana;` being the property of that child), ignoring any other `font-family` property in the entire document/stylesheet.

Visual result looks like this (without `, verdana` the third container with text would also be in Times New Roman):

[image: IE11 in Virtual Machine running Windows 7 (test-drive) shows how font-family does not work correctly]

**Observations**

- This should work with **any custom font**, it is not specific to SassoonInfant. Also, the `@font-face` should work just fine cross-browser.
- **Timing is essential**: Timeout is needed to reproduce this bug, I suppose it only appears when I add nested element if font has already been loaded.
- **Order** of `txt.style.fontFamily`, `txt.innerHTML`, `appendChild(txt)` is important to reproduce the bug. And all these statements need to be in the timeout-function.
- Already having a parent and child in the DOM tree, both with `font-family: SassoonInfant` will **solve** this bug. Further nesting does not make any difference, neither does extra nesting in the dynamically added element make any difference. Thus changing `font-family: arial;` from the first child of the `<body>` to `font-family: SassoonInfant;` will fix this bug.
- It makes no difference when the `txt`-element is created, but it has to be created **dynamically**. So using `document.getElementById('textcontainer')` with `#textcontainer` already within the `#container` will solve this bug.
- The behavior of this bug is very similar (or equal) to that of **setting an undefined custom** for the `font-family` in IE10+, as can be seen in the second child of the `<body>`.

**Question**

What is the underlying cause of this bug? And even though I have already supplied some conditions in which this bug is solved, are there any better solutions that maybe are global. Like some property you can add to the `<body>` or `@font-face` to solve this?

**Follow-up**

Although maybe it's related to the `hasLayout`-property of IE (but adding `zoom: 1;` did not really help), and thus it is not technically a bug. Should it be reported?